# How to navigate to external URL without Angular prepending "localhost:xxxx"?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I'm trying to write a guard that, if the user is not logged in, redirects to an external service (say, Instagram),

```
if (!loggedIn) {
   this.location.go(this.instagramLoginUri);
}
```

where `location` is an instance of Angular's `Location` and the URI is

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxx&response_type=token
```

When this guard triggers, Angular tries to navigate to

```
http://localhost:4200/https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxx&response_type=token
```

which fails, of course. I tried using

```
window.location.href = 'xxxxx'
```

as well, with the exact same result, so I'm not sure this is indeed Angular related. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this:

```
 constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

 if (!loggedIn) {
    this.document.location.href = 'http://instagram.com';
 }
```

Comment: That actually works - now I'd like to know what the difference between these approaches is.

Comment: Location is responsible for normalizing the URL against the application's base href. as Angular website says https://angular.io/api/common/Location.